# Reading a specific cell in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to read a csv file line by line, in each iteration I need to compare the word that appears in the first column of this line to the word that appears in the same place in the next line.
Then I’ll copy values respectively.

When I copy the line from the csv file to an array, all the values are in the same cell so I can’t work with it.

I want to work with panda,  so I need to choose columns by index- how can i do this?

I’m looking for solution for that, thank you :)

[example for a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHdxY.png)

Comment: can you show a line from your csv file?

Comment: in my post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear I hope I'm answering the right way. Try transforming your csv into pandas dataframe called for example df then call for df.values

Comment: I loop over the lines of the file.
i need to get through all the variables in a row one by one without getting them all, can you help me with that?

Comment: df.values is an array form of the dataframe, all you have to do is to loop on the first index to loop over lines, for example:
 for i in range(len(df.values)):
                print(df.values[i, :])

Answer (score 0):

If you have read out the lines already (as you write in the comment to the other answer) - those are strings - you can split them into a list with `variable_containing_line.split(',')` - replace the ',' by whatever character is appropriate, if the split character is not a comma.

the `split()`-method returns you a list of the parts.

It seems, you should then loop through all pairs of your first elements of these lines. Maybe with enumerate, more elegant probably with zip:

```
for i, j in zip(first_elements[1:], first_elements[:-1]):
    if i==j:
         do_something()
```